# Using command line to find and replace?

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, command

I'm trying to use command line to find and replace some text.  I have a file with a few million lines that are similar to this:

```
Something-Here/Grafton-WV</loc>
More-Information/Claremore-OK</loc>
This-Is-It/Seminole-OK</loc>
Your-Company/Lunenburg-MA</loc>
```

What I need to do is remove the slash and everything after it.  I've done wildcard find/replace before but I'm not sure what command would need to be used to start at the slash and continue until the end of the line.

Here's what the output should be:

```
Something-Here
More-Information
This-Is-It
Your-Company
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following one-liner could work for you:

```
perl -pe 's{/.*}{}' file.txt
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `s{/.*}{}`: Remove all characters after the first forward slash from the line

Comment: @jaypal It's exactly the same as Barmar's substitution: replace `/.*` with the empty string. Perhaps you're referring to the use of balanced delimiters `{` and `}` in the substitution operator?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Yes, sorry I wasn't clear. AFAIK the delimiters needs to be consistent. Seeing `{` and `}` together kinda threw me off.

Comment: @jaypal You can also use `()`, `<>`, and `[]` in the same way.

Comment: @jaypal In this case, none, but consider the following: `s|(foo|bar)|baz|` (doesn't work) vs. `s{\d{3}}{foo}` (works). It's nice to not have to worry about escaping all instances of the delimiter in your regex.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually done with `sed`:

```
sed 's|/.*||' file.txt > newfile.txt
```